# PDFsharp adding link not working

Tags: c#, image, pdf, hyperlink, pdfsharp

I am trying to create a PDF with an image in it and resize the PDF and add a link to it. I am doing this so I can embed a link into my image to use in multiple projects. I am using PDFsharp. I had it working fine with a link on the image but when I resized the PDF page then my link would no longer work.

```
private static void createPDF()
{
    string image = "C:\\download.png";
    string filename = "C:\\Test.pdf";
    PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
    PdfPage page = doc.AddPage();
    XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
    AddImage(gfx, page, image, 0, 0);
    doc.Save(filename);
}
private static void AddImage(XGraphics gfx, PdfPage page, string imagePath, int xPosition, int yPosition)
{
    if (!File.Exists(imagePath))
    {
        throw new FileNotFoundException(String.Format("Could not find image {0}.", imagePath));
    }

    XImage xImage = XImage.FromFile(imagePath);
    page.Width = xImage.PixelWidth;
    page.Height = xImage.PixelHeight;
    gfx.DrawImage(xImage, xPosition, yPosition, xImage.PixelWidth, xImage.PixelHeight);
    XRect rec = gfx.Transformer.WorldToDefaultPage(new XRect(new XPoint(xPosition, yPosition), new XSize(page.Width, page.Height)));
    PdfRectangle rect = new PdfRectangle(rec);
    page.AddWebLink(rect, "http://www.google.com");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is: you have to set Width and Height of the page before obtaining the XGraphics object.

So re-arranging just a few lines of code actually does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my problem right after I posted the question.

```
private static void AddImage(XGraphics gfx, PdfPage page, string imagePath, int xPosition, int yPosition)
{
    if (!File.Exists(imagePath))
    {
        throw new FileNotFoundException(String.Format("Could not find image {0}.", imagePath));
    }

    XRect rec = gfx.Transformer.WorldToDefaultPage(new XRect(new XPoint(xPosition, yPosition), new XSize(page.Width, page.Height)));
    PdfRectangle rect = new PdfRectangle(rec);
    page.AddWebLink(rect, "http://www.google.com");
    XImage xImage = XImage.FromFile(imagePath);
    page.Width = xImage.PixelWidth;
    page.Height = xImage.PixelHeight;
    gfx.DrawImage(xImage, xPosition, yPosition, xImage.PixelWidth, xImage.PixelHeight);
}
```

I just rearanged a few lines of code.

Comment: This may seem to work, but I'm afraid it will not always work. Set width and height of the page before calling `XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);` and things should be correct.